# How to Upload Image to Firebase Storage & Save Image url to Firebase Database to use it in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

i need to  get an image link from firebase storage and save its url to a firestore field ,
i have a collect with a field called avatar(string) ,  the avatar value is an images link from the firebase storage

---

```
  ClipRRect(
                                      child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index].data['avatar'],
                                        height: 100,
                                        width: 170,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    ),
```

---

and the error code

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): Unsupported scheme 'gs' in URI gs://pfe-2020-51d9c.appspot.com/Ail/14118b537d_100727_bienfaits-ail.jpg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2278:9)
#1      _HttpClient.getUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2197:48)
#2      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:84:59)
#3      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:47:14)
#4      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:327:17)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("gs://pfe-2020-51d9c.appspot.com/Ail/14118b537d_100727_bienfaits-ail.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("gs://pfe-2020-51d9c.appspot.com/Ail/14118b537d_100727_bienfaits-ail.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Create File variable to hold you image:

> You can use [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) to choose an image from phone.

```
File file;
```

**2)** Create function to Choose an image

```
handleChooseImageFromGallery() async {
File _file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  this.file = _file;
});
}
```

> you can pass **ImageSource.camera** in **source** if you want to take an image with the phone camera.

**3)** Uploading image to firebase storage

```
Future<String> handleUploadImage(imageFile) async {
// Upload imageFile to firebase storage
// TODO: use uuid for pictureId

StorageUploadTask uploadTask =
    storageRef.child("${user.id}_profilePic_$picId.jpg").putFile(imageFile);
StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
// Once the image is uploaded to firebase get the download link.
String downlaodUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
return downlaodUrl;
}
```

**This function will return the image url.**

**4)** Saving the image url in firestore document

```
void handleUpdateUserProfile()
{
    String mediaUrl = await handleUploadImage(file); // Pass your file variable 
    // Create/Update firesotre document
    usersRef.document(userId).updateData(
    {
        "avatar": mediaUrl,
    }
    );
}
```

Comment: i dont think there is a simpler way to do so. All you have to do is to choose an image from your phone --> Upload it to firebase storage and get the url in return --> store the url in firestore and use it in you app.